# How to update existing lambda function using AWS SAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-serverless, aws-sam

I have some lambda functions that have been created before moving to AWS SAM. I would like to update my existing lambda function using AWS SAM. What would be the process of referencing the lambda function in AWS SAM. I have a lambda function already created called: hello.

How would I update the lambda function using AWS SAM? below is my sam template.yaml file

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Description: CD Demo Lambda
Resources:
  hello:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: lambda_function.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.7
      CodeUri: ./s3lambda
      FunctionName: hello
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 03
```

Answer (score 1):

As [AWS SAM](https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/sam/) uses `Cloudformation` for deploying resources.

You need to import the lambdas [Importing existing resources into a stack](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-existing-stack.html) in the `cloudformation` stack.

Comment: thank you for your response. just one question: how would I reference the stack in the template.yaml file?

Comment: as per the documentation, you start with the template.
>During this import, you need to provide a template that describes the entire stack, including the target resources. If existing stack resources are modified in the prepared template, the import fails.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-template-resources-error/) states that you cannot import resources to AWS SAM Templates.

Answer (score 0):

The answers here are not so useful for beginners.

If you want to update your AWS Lambda function using SAM-CLI, I guess that you already deployed a function with `sam deploy --guided` command. SAM helped you to deploy your app with CloudFormation and saved the configuration in the `samconfig.toml` file.

Next time you can deploy your app just by giving the stack-name and (at least in my case) the S3 Bucket where your Lambda Function is placed.

`sam deploy --stack-name YOUR-APP-NAME --s3-bucket YOUR-BUCKET-NAME`